# Recover deleted file or folder from git repository

Tags: xcode, git, repository

I installed a Git repository through the Apple App (Server) everything works correctly up to here no problem. For error in my Xcode project I deleted some files, now I want to restore all my deleted files from an old commit. I can not find any work to recover these files. Can someone kindly help me? 
thanks really.

Comment: what says the `git status`? in most cases it is enough to call `git checkout file`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git reset` but other people which uses your repo may have some issues with repo. 
Also you can try `git revert`, [see more](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert.html).

Comment: Thank you. I thought you could do file recovery via a graphical interface of Xcode. thanks for the support.